# Как использовать Вывод даных через переменную

Tags: php, get

Файл php2.php

```
<?php
#здесь некие расчеты с данными переменной $per2 и постом результата в echo
echo $per2;
?>
```

Файл php1.php

```
<?php
$per2 = '2';
$count = header("Location: php2.php?per2=".$per2);
echo $count*2;
# в результате нужно, чтобы файл php1.php возвратил результат [4]
?>
```

Не могу получить данные расчетов из второго файла таким образом. Нужна помощь. fopen() тоже пробовал

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю вам нужно почитать про [функции](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.returning-values.php)

Так же вы вы можете в файле [выполнить скрипт](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php) php1.php и получить то что он выводит в переменную.

```
$count = exec('php php1.php'); // или shell_exec('php php1.php')
```

Comment: Не совсем то, что нужно, т.к. сам файл php2.php является сторонней библиотекой

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно header("Location: php2.php?per2=".$per2); это перенаправление,т.е оно проходит не на уровне сценария скрипта, а перенаправляет на другую страницу в браузере, данные нужно принимать $_GET['per2']; Но после того как вы перенаправили пользователя на страницу php2.php естественно на текущей странице ничего не поменяется, и данные ни откуда не придут, вам тогда нужно делать include('php2.php');  передавать туда данные через переменную, в общем у вас проблемы со структурой, определитесь что вы конкретно хотите получить.

Answer (score 0):

Не думал что у вас(и у других), такой вопрос вызовет кучу вопросов.

**Файл php2.php**

```
<?php
#здесь некие расчеты с данными переменной $per2 и постом результата в echo
echo $per2;
```

**Файл php1.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();

include('php2.php');

$OUT = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $OUT;
```

---

**P.S.** Если вам нужно что-то передать в `php2.php`, то исходя из ваших слов:

> т.к. сам файл php2.php является сторонней библиотекой

могу подсказать следующее:

1) `include` работает в той-же области видимости что и текущий кусок кода, вызвавший этот `include`, т.е.:

```
$var_for_include = 4;
include(php2.php);
```

А в самом `php2.php`, можно использовать: `echo $var_for_include * 2;`.

2) Либы - это обычно классы, с интерфейсом и функциями для работы с ними, поэтому вы можете делать так:

```
ob_start();

$var_for_include = 4;
include(php2.php);
includeClass::method($var_for_include);

$OUT = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $OUT;
```

А в самом `php2.php`:

```
class includeClass
{
    public static function method($var) {
        echo $var*2;
    }
}
```